# Temporarily deactive onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could someone tell me how you can deactivate the event onchange and reactivate it

```
 $(':checkbox').each(function (k, v) {
     $(this).onchange = null;//
     $(this).off() // works but I do not know how to  reactivate onchange event
 })
```

Edit 1:
Let me explain you my problem ... I'm using bootstrap toggle onmy checkbox. But maybe this is only a detail.

SO my problem is .. I  have a "reset" button on my form. When I click on it, I   have a function who loops on each checkbox of my form trying to "reset" each checkbox. By reseting my checkbox I mean setting them to their initial value. . . but doing so I trigger an "onchange" function present later in my code. And I do not want to trigger that "onchange" function

Comment: .(this).prop('disabled',true).delay (500).prop('disabled',false)

Comment: So you want to *disable* the `onchange` event and than reenable it? Why don't you just exit the function and not unbind the event.

Comment: What do you mean by *Temporarily*  exactly ? And you do not need the `.each` here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend one of two options.

First, you can unbind and rebind the handlers by giving the function a name:

```
function handleCheckboxClick(e) {
    //...
}

$(':checkbox').off('change');
$(':checkbox').on('change', handleCheckboxClick);
```

The other option is to create a variable that you set to `true` or `false` as needed to specify whether to execute the handler:

```
$(':checkbox').on('change', function(e) {
    if (!window.shouldExecuteCheckboxChangeHandler)
        return;

    //...
});
```

Comment: Thank you man ! After hours of tries I've implemented something working fine.
I choose your second solution. I set a property to window object and use it as a flag (true or false)

Comment: This will only work if you know all the handlers, which you normally won't. If other libraries/plugins have attached handlers to your element, you'll break them all.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(this).prop('disabled',true).delay (500).prop('disabled',false)
```

Comment: 500 is half a second

Comment: Yea?it usually used between animations..?

Comment: Delaying one funcction   https://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=https://api.jquery.com/delay/&ei=zkgOsfIk&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=881&host=www.google.co.in&ts=1470938868&sig=AKOVD6566D6Zygc7VqkLq0MVy7t_kO8FKA

Comment: `.delay()` only works for queued animations. It does not work with `.prop()` because it does not get queued up. `.prop()` takes effect immediately.

Answer (score -1):

You can disable and enable element.

```
$(':checkbox').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$(':checkbox').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `on` and `off`:

```
 $(':checkbox').each(function (k, v) {

     $(this).off("change", myFunction)

     //do stuff

     $(this).on("change", myFunction)

 }
 function myFunction(e) {
    //your event handling code
 }
```

You will also need to use `myFunction` when you initially set the handler.